# How to add static html text to New Item form in sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online

﻿﻿I have New Item Form where Under Title column I need add some static text sentence using javascript. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I think you need to have a default value in a site column. SharePoint already does have this feature. Go to list settings. Select the site column in which you need to have the default value and give the default content.

Comment: I don't want to set default content to any column, I want to show static text like consider as Note to user while filling up New item form. I want to show the text below Title column of new item form of List

Answer (score 1):

The field description shows under the field on the form.
Edit the field and add a description.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a picture for @moldypenguins answer:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir. I know this thing. but I dont want to set in description as there are some other conditions too. I want to add just simple text sentence below Title column as Note or information for the user.

Comment: If you are not using the "modern UI" for the list, then just edit the forms in SharePoint Designer and add the text or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I was waiting for any response but at the end , I have created script. It might be useful for others. :)

var textYes = "your Text";

$("#Title").after(textYes);

Regards,

Shraddha07

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  There are a few steps to take but you can add a field below the columns in the new form and use code to fill them out.  First thing you will need to do is create a custom NewForm.aspx page in SPD for the list.  What this will do is open up the back end coding on the NewForm.aspx for you.  You can then find the table data used to build the form.  Find your field, and place a new  item into the table under the Title column in the table used to create the form.  Give it an ID, and you can write the code to fill it out on the custom form itself.  The key is creating a custom NewForm.aspx file in SPD to open up the code for you to add your extra field.  Then add your logic to your new field with JS and there you go.